# Can object method have own propertis?

Tags: javascript

For function I can make this:

```
uniqueInteger.counter = 0;

function uniqueInteger() {
    return uniqueInteger.counter++; // Increment and return counter property
}
```

Can I do this also with object method?

Comment: what do you mean by object method?

Comment: Yes you can. Object methods are still functions. Why, what happened when you tried it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can, because [functions are first class objects](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Functions):

> In JavaScript, functions are first-class objects, because they can have properties and methods just like any other object. What distinguishes them from other objects is that functions can be called. In brief, they are [Function](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function) objects.

```js
var object = {
        x: function () { return this.x.value; }
    };

object.x.value = 42;
document.write(object.x());
```

Answer (score 0):

Objects methods are functions. You can do this for any function:

```
var a = function () { }
a.bar = "f";

for(property in a) {
 console.log(a[property]);
}
// outputs f
```

However, please note that "own property" has a specific meaning in javascript, to the point that it's highly recommended to check if a property is object's own property when iterating through the properties (e.g. to ignore inherited properties).

```
o = new Object();
o.prop = 'exists';
o.hasOwnProperty('prop');             // returns true
o.hasOwnProperty('toString');         // returns false
o.hasOwnProperty('hasOwnProperty');   // returns false
```